# FormatException when typing "done" in console. C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to output average when user enters "done", but it does not compile and says "FormatException". I tried everything I could do. I want program to output average when user enters done, without FormatException. If I try/catch(FormatException) it catches exception but I want average to be printed to the screen. I have declared if block, but It does not help. Maybe I have incorrect placement of lines. I guess program converts input to double value, before it reaches if block, so it can't compare double value and string value.Hope you can understand my question.

```
  using System;

  namespace Averager
  {
  class Program
  {
    static void Main()
    {

        int inputCount = 0;
        double total = 0;

        while(true){

           Console.Write("Please enter a number or type \"done\" to see an 
           average:  ");
           string num1 = Console.ReadLine();
           double _num1 = double.Parse(num1);
           inputCount++;
           total += _num1;
           Console.WriteLine("Total is " + total);   

           double average = total/inputCount;

           if(num1.ToLower() == "done"){
              Console.WriteLine("Average:  "+ average);
           }                                              
     }       
    }
}
```

}

Comment: double.Parse("done") is not going to work, look for "done" before assuming its a number.

Comment: Put `if(num1.ToLower() == "done")` immediately after the `Console.ReadLine()` and use `else{ }` to execute when value is not "done". Also use `double.TryParse` to determine if a value is number or string

Comment: BTW, how does your program stop/end?

Comment: I wanted to take care of that Exception, I will work for stopping program and other things too. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is caused by trying to parse without checking if the value is a number or a string. In your case whenever you don't enter a number you will get an exception.

```
 string num1 = Console.ReadLine();
 // if num1 contains anything else then a number you will get an exception
 double _num1 = double.Parse(num1);
```

Here is how to do it:

```
static void Main()
    {

        int inputCount = 0;
        double total = 0;
        double _num1 = 0;
        double average = 0;

        while (true)
        {

            Console.Write("Please enter a number or type done to see an  average: ");

            string num1 = Console.ReadLine();

            if (double.TryParse(num1, out _num1))
            {
                inputCount++;

                total += _num1;

                Console.WriteLine("Total is " + total);

                average = total / inputCount;
            }
            else if(num1.ToLower() == "done")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Average:  " + average);
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Something went wrong");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer would be better if you provided the "right" way of doing it.

Comment: @JohnyL I used it to break out of the loop. If you don't put in `break` the loop will keep running forever.

Comment: If you are having trouble understanding this code I can suggest you to check out these tutorials by [Derek Banas](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0p0JLFZj2C8&list=PLGLfVvz_LVvRX6xK1oi0reKci6ignjdSa). He does a really good job of explaining how this stuff works.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the Programm DOES compile and DOES run. FormatException is a runtime exception. It is thrown specifically by the [Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fd84bdyt.aspx#Exceptions) functions. And because you give it a random string ("done") that can not possibly evaluate to a number

You have a few choices:

1. Check for the string "done" before you feed it to parse. It is a basic if. The main issue is that alternate spellings would not be detected properly.
2. You could use [TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse.aspx). And print out on anything that does not result in a valid parsed number. It is harder to use, but it was designed to get around the sometimes vexing exceptions Parse can throw.

When you are starting to deal with Exceptions seriously, here are two Articles are worth reading:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET